# How to build QtWebEngine 5.10 from source

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I'm trying to build QtWebengine from source so what I've done is I downloaded qtwebengine from http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/

I've also installed all the depencies listed on http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/How_to_Try

I followed the steps to cd into the folder and ran

```
git submodule update --init
```

then qmake
but I got this error:

```
~/Documents/qtwebengine 5.10
❯ qmake -r
Cannot read /home/austin/Documents/qtwebengine/qtwebengine-config.pri: No such file or directory
/home/austin/Documents/qtwebengine/mkspecs/features/platform.prf:68: 'qtConfig' is not a recognized test function.
/home/austin/Documents/qtwebengine/mkspecs/features/configure.prf:33: 'qtConfig' is not a recognized test function.

Required gperf could not be found.
QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

Do I need to create my own qtwebengine-config.pri file?

ps: I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: `Required gperf could not be found.` — @applepie, is not it like saying that it cannot find an specific version of **gperf** tool needed for build?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, solution worked for me was:

#### install all dependencies: wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

#### 1) build qt 5.10

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qt5

cd qt5

perl init-repository --module-subset=default,-qtwebengine

./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests

make
```

#### 2) after qt5.10 builded same steps

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qwebeng

cd qwebeng

perl init-repository --module-subset=qtwebengine,qtwebplugin,qtwebsoskets,qtwebview

cd qtwebengine

/yourQt5.10dir/base/bin/qmake

make -j
```

Comment: note that all dependies should be installed use https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Comment: info : on qt.5.9 and later on i used to delete qtwebengine directory,